# Data enrichment using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

Currently, there is a spring batch application which is used to enrich file based data. Data is enriched by calling various APIs. If I migrate data enrichment process to Azure Data Factory, can I call APIs from data pipeline? Is this the right solution or is there any other alternative Azure provides ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call APIs from data pipeline.

To perform the Copy activity with a pipeline, you can use one of the following tools or SDKs:

•   The Copy Data tool

•   The Azure portal

•   The .NET SDK

•   The Python SDK

•   Azure PowerShell

•   The REST API

•   The Azure Resource Manager template

Refer - [Copy and transform data from and to a REST endpoint by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory)

Also Refer this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/integrating-apis-into-data-pipelines-with-azure-data-factory/) by  Gauri Mahajan